# How to make sbt output detail log info

Tags: scala, sbt

I am compiling a scala project using sbt commands:

```
java -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal -jar /usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar
```

and the result windows is aways stay in:

```
[info] Loading settings from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from /home/hldev/hldata/backend/knowledge-system/project
[info] Updating ProjectRef(uri("file:/home/hldev/hldata/backend/knowledge-system/project/"), "knowledge-system-build")...
```

for an hour,I do not know what happen to the compile,is network failed? too many scala to compiling?How to make the console to log the detail status info so I could know what happen.I am aready read the [sbt document](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Running.html).

Comment: Is this your first project using  scala SBT ?

Comment: If yes, then just wait because your system also download and update its dependencies in order to run your Project

Comment: No, this project is writen by another guy.I just pull and copile it@Rex. I wait for too long,maybe two hours.

Comment: It must be someting wrong.It's too long to update.@Rex

Comment: Yeah, I encounter same before but sometimes network problem.

Comment: Did you try to change the `SBT version` and `scala version` used on the project ?

Comment: It is some package could not get from internet.But it should be failed as soon as possible.It take toooooooooooo much time to wasted.@Rex

Comment: I think we don't have choice because while compiling the `sbt console` gives details already.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Launcher script for running sbt](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package/blob/57ab435306e75e82b7ca9a965cf39a7973d60ed9/src/universal/bin/sbt#L425) gives the following options:

```
Usage: sbt [options]

  -h | -help         print this message
  -v | -verbose      this runner is chattier
  -d | -debug        set sbt log level to debug
...
```

so you could try running with

```
sbt -verbose -debug
```

to get more information.